Unable to upload file to gdrive using gdrive api with service account
I am using a service account created in Google cloud platform to upload csv files to gdrive using a python script. This script was working file till yesterday but now I am getting below error.
Script:
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
gdrive = 'D:/common-modules/gdrive.json'
folder_id = "1IxxxxyYxxxx"


def upload_option_strike_data(save_location, file_name):
    try:
        creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(gdrive, scopes=scopes)
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
        file_metadata = {
            'name': file_name,
            'parents': [folder_id]
        }
        file_path = f"{save_location}/{file_name}"
        media = MediaFileUpload(file_path, mimetype='text/csv')

        service.files().create(
            body=file_metadata,
            media_body=media
        ).execute()
        print(f"Successfully uploaded historical data collected for to Gdrive")
    except Exception as e:
        print(
            f"Failed to upload historical data collected for .Function - upload_option_strike_data.Exception: {str(e)}")



upload_option_strike_data("D:/daily-data/output", "FINNIFTY_OptionData_20240514.csv")

Error Message:
Failed to upload historical data collected for .Function - upload_option_strike_data.Exception: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded.". Details: "[{'message': "The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded.", 'domain': 'usageLimits', 'reason': 'storageQuotaExceeded'}]">

I am using 200GB storage plan and is currently 143GB used.
Each of my csv files will be around 7MB size. When I upload a small file with size around 100KB, files are getting uploaded without any issues. Error indicates about storageQuotaExceeded, but unable to identify this quota setting (dont see anything from GCP console)
How to resolve this issue ?

Try doing an about.get it will show you how much space is available.
If you are storing files on the service accounts drive account its very limited as far as space goes and you can't upgrade it

"quotaBytesTotal": "214748364800",
"quotaBytesUsed": "3321699110",
"quotaBytesUsedInTrash": "0",
"largestChangeId": "286410",
And also I am uploading the files to my own gdrive folder, not on service account drive

When a file is upload by a service account it is first on its account and then moved to where ever parents is set.  Are you sure that parent directory is on your account.  Do a files list to see what is on the service accounts drive account

thanks. I was not aware that files will copy to the service account drive. Checked it and found it was using full quota of 15GB. I deleted the files and now my script is working fine
